# Understanding the behavior of Gremlin's coalesce in a concurrent environment

Tags: concurrency, graph-databases, gremlin, unique-constraint, tinkerpop

The following query adds an edge between two vertices only if it doesn't exist.

```
g.V('ea36e68a-70c5-4d38-a038-f5145ed4ced7').as('v').
  V('e3516889-7df0-4cc9-b240-2aa0dba75280').
  coalesce(__.inE('follows').where(outV().as('v')), addE('follows').from('v'))
```

My question is, what happens if this query was to be executed in a highly concurrent setting? Would there be a possibility of reading the same "exists" criteria and creating multiple edges? I'm new to graph databases, and it looks like there is no uniqueness constraint we could  enforce like in SQL. My goal is to make sure some edges can only be created once (e.g. `follows` or `likes`). How should I approach this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior you get is not enforced or determined by Gremlin. It is up to the underlying graph database that you choose. Some will just update after a dirty read, while others might throw some sort of error for concurrently modifying the data which would mean you would have to retry the traversal. Some graphs do have a notion of a schema which enables you to enforce various constraints including edge cardinality. I think that the graph you choose will dictate how you best deal with this issue (or perhaps you allow this issue to dictate the graph you choose).

Comment: Thank you, Stephen. I'm considering using Azure's Cosmos DB graph. Are you aware of how it behaves regarding this issue?

Comment: i'm not 100% certain, but they have tunable consistency levels https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/consistency-levels so i would imagine you have some control there.